# Using IIS 7 I keep getting the error message Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to setup phpmyadmin to be  used on iis7 but once i set up a new site and gave the site the phpmyadmin files to run it will not allow me to connect.

any ideas on how i can get around this or set up phpmyadmin for use on iis7 for all my sites please.

Many Thanks

Comment: Which error message do you get?